# "Normal distributed" or "normally distributed"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I am not sure if I should use an adjective or an adverb in the following sentences.

> - The returns are normal distributed.
> - The returns are normally distributed.

Also see this example:

> - The most famous approach assumes the returns to be normal distributed.
> - The most famous approach assumes the returns to be normally distributed.

Which is correct?

Comment: "Returns" is probably not the right word to use here; "results" or "values" might be better.

Answer (score 4):

*Distributed* is a past participle and it is used as a verb.

For this reason, in both sentences you should use ***normally***, which is an adverb, instead of *normal* which, being an adjective, generally accompanies a noun.

Comment: oh really, so "The returns are normally distributed" I expected that normal would be correct, but ok, thanks!

Comment: Yes, and we say _normal distribution_ for the same reason (i.e., we use the adjective, because _distribution_ is a noun). [Have a look](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=normal+distributed%2Cnormally+distributed%2C+normal+distribution%2C+normally+distribution&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).